# Using TotpSecurityStampBasedTokenProvider for TOTP with Google Authenticator

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, totp

I'm implementing 2FA using TOTP on my asp.net web api 2 webservice (NOT .net core).

The implementation uses the [TotpSecurityStampBasedTokenProvider](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/TotpSecurityStampBasedTokenProvider.cs) which is provided by the Microsoft.AspNet.Identity framework.

When looking at Google Authenticator requirements it lists that the secret needs to be a base32 encoded string.

If you look at the code from the TotpSecurityStampBasedTokenProvider it uses the user's SecurityStamp as the secret which is generated by the Identity Framework. This is a GUID and not a base32 encoded string.

According to the specifications for the [Google Authenticator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Authenticator) there is a requirement that the secret is a base32 encoded string.

How can I use the TotpSecurityStampBasedTokenProvider for use with Google Authenticator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the [TotpSecurityStampBasedTokenProvider](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/TotpSecurityStampBasedTokenProvider.cs) provided by [Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity) implements a hardcoded timestep of **3 minutes**. Google Authenticator uses a default value of **30 seconds**, which **can NOT be modified** according to the documentation [provided](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator/wiki/Key-Uri-Format).

This causes different codes to be generated by both TOTP computations resulting in an always false authentication.

I have added a ticket to the [github repository of aspnet.identity](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/issues/15) about this.

So for now nothing left for me to do than create my own totpProvider

Answer (score 2):

The [TotpSecurityStampBasedTokenProvider](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/TotpSecurityStampBasedTokenProvider.cs) uses [UserManager.CreateSecurityTokenAsync](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/master/src/Core/UserManager.cs#L2363) to generate the secret code which is used to calculate the token.

The code relies on the user ID, and is generated into a byte array, which is usually shown as base-32 or QR code on-screen to the user in the TOTP setup phase.

So long story short, there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thank you Patrick, can you tell me which method I need to use on the UserManager to get the secret as a byte[] to encode into base-32 for the setup phase? I was using UserManager.GetSecurityStampAsync but that must be where my implementation is wrong.

Comment: That would be `GetSecurityStampAsync` or `CreateSecurityTokenAsync` probably.

Comment: You're right, I was encoding the secret to a byte array using the incorrect encoding . I should use unicode. Thank you for the insight!

Comment: Yes, indeed. Good you found it.

Comment: The sample projects are usually quite useful. See for example here: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/master/samples/IdentitySample.Mvc/Controllers/AccountController.cs